# LibGDX getting max texture size - null pointer exception

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, libgdx

I try to get max texture size on device where app is running:

```
protected int getMaxTextureSize() {
    IntBuffer buf = BufferUtils.newIntBuffer(16);
    Gdx.gl.glGetIntegerv(GL20.GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE, buf); //here is null pointer exception
    return buf.get();
}
```

and app crashes when I use it:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.ResourceManager.getMaxTextureSize(ResourceManager.java:32)
    at com.example.ResourceManager.<init>(ResourceManager.java:23)
    at com.example.Game.<init>(Game.java:17)
    at com.example.desktop.DesktopLauncher.main(DesktopLauncher.java:15)
```

(on Android same exception appears)

Why? Every forum or docs say it is correct.

Comment: Are you sure you are calling this after the GL context was properly initialized. The stack stace looks like `dx.gl.glGetIntegerv` itself could be NULL.

Comment: @derhass: Thanks. That was it :) Please make an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stack trace shows that the NullPointerException does not happen inside `Gdx.gl.glGetIntegerv`, strongly indicating that `Gdx.gl.glGetIntegerv` itself might be a NULL pointer.

Since `glGetIntegerv` is a core function which must be present in all versions of GL and GLES, the most plausible explanation is that you call this function before the GL binding is properly initialized.

For this function to return meaningful values, you will always need a valid GL context in any case, so you must move it to some point after the GL context is created.